# How to make thread not crashing application

Tags: c#, multithreading

Let's assume I have following console application:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { throw new Exception(); }));
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();

while (true)
  Console.WriteLine("Hello from main thread");
```

Is it possible to make entire application not crashing because of background tread's exception (without using try..catch of course)?

Comment: "without using try..catch **of course**" o_O

Comment: try/catch/finally is created to handle exceptions. What's wrong with using them?

Comment: I'm trying to do fault-tolerant application, so I want to avoid unhandled and unexpected exceptions to crash entire application

Comment: @user1121956 you starting a thread and throwing an exception ? doesnt sound fault tolerant to me. if you want to continue down this path (for whatever reason) use try/catch/finally to handle exceptions, thats what they are there for.

Comment: **I'm trying to do fault-tolerant application** :   That's the reason, why you SHOULD use try-catch. Logical, isn't it?

Comment: An app that is tolerant to faults, with no exception handling?

Comment: So write code to catch and recover from exceptions!

Comment: no, my exception is just example, I'm trying to prevent execution of UNEXPECTED exceptions

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think he is trying to handle exceptions thrown from another thread. So the thread will have to just throw it.

Comment: @BartFriederichs do you mean to catch exception e.g. from background thread in the main thread? how can I do that?

Comment: I mean, I could use try catch but outside thread in which exception is thrown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attach your unhandled exceptions handler:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

The better way you can achieve desired result (Ok, with try/catch, but only once) with global handler:

```
    public static void GlobalHandler(ThreadStart threadStartTarget)
    {
        try
        {
            threadStartTarget.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             //handle exception here
        }
    }
```

And then start your threads:

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(o => GlobalHandler(ThreadMethod));
        thread.Start();
```

P.S. However, really, I don't like idea of catching all exceptions. It is *almost* never good idea.

Comment: nice idea, however it just notify, doesn't prevent from crash, does it?

Comment: @user1121956 Well, you should just notify and exit. However, there is no time limit for handler operation. So, _technically_, you can proceed with your operations inside handler. However, this is really bad idea.

Comment: Nice! I will do Thread class wrapper like that (because Thread is sealed) to have place where I can keep catched exceptions. In fact BackgroundWorker do similar job except it doesn't necessary creates new thread. Thanks for idea

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ThreadPool` thread.

Comment: It will not help. Unhanded exceptions from ThreadPool threads will crash application the same way as from manually created Thread.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to hide unhanded exception and forget about it, so don't do it.

I am not sure why you don't want to use try/catch but it is the best way to handle the situation, in which case you should fix exception if you can, or at least log it for later review

Comment: Right, first answer will be able to do both - log and still not crash app (unless the exceptions which can't be cought)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you CAN **catch** unhandled exceptions globally, you shoud be aware that there are some exceptions that you might be able to catch, but not to **handle**. StackoverflowException might not leave enough stackspace to handle the exception. Same with OutOfMemory. There MIGHT not be enough space for a large object, but there's also a chance that there is no space left at all.
So you usually write code to catch and handle THOSE exceptions that you CAN handle (filenotfound, accessviolation etc) and leave all others to crash your app (better crash than continue in undefined state). The only thing you could do with an unhandled exception: TRY to gracefully close your app (saving some changes, writing an error log or whatever) and THE rethrow the exception.

Comment: My architecture separates tasks intoto separated threads in the way there is no state loose if they crash. It's like I could even make separated process for each of task.

Comment: When something _strange_ happens in the middle of _something_ (for example somewhere in the frameworks functions) how would you handle it? You cant. You do not even know if the CLR itself might be in an inconsistent state. And you want to continue your app as if nothing had happened? Doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: I don't. If some exception is thrown, thread should just end its life, not continue to work. The question is how to make it not killing entire application as other threads can work anyway

Comment: However you're right that this exceptions like StackOverflow are cases which can't be supported anyway, so I should be aware of that, thanks for input